# Retrieving a key from HashMap based on part of certain strings in the key?

Tags: java

Task: Read a XML file to create a Template;

I am reading this XML file as mentioned below and putting it in a HashMap. to get a Key-Value pair, 
where Key is value under Element attribute "name" and Value is Element Value.
eg: Key: map.abc.color.PRIMARY and Value: #FFFFFF
eg: Key: map.abc.node.TEXT1 and Value: value1

```
<properties>
    <property name="map.abc.color.PRIMARY">#FFFFFF</property>
    <property name="map.abc.color.SECONDARY">#F0F0F0</property>
    <property name="map.abc.node.TEXT1">value1</property>
    <property name="map.abc.node.TEXT2">value2</property>
    <property name="map.abc.node.lowercase">value3</property>   
    <property name="map.abc.strFile">/path/to/file</property>

    <property name="map.pqr.color.PRIMARY">#000000</property>
    <property name="map.pqr.color.SECONDARY">#ABABAB</property>
    <property name="map.pqr.node.WORD1">value4</property>
    <property name="map.pqr.node.WORD2">value5</property>
    <property name="map.abc.node.lowercase">value6</property>
    <property name="map.pqr.strFile">/path/to/file</property>
</properties>
```

Following is a Template(using a StringBuffer) Output to be written to a file.

```
abc = {
    color: {PRIMARY_COLOR:"#FFFFFF",SECONDARY_COLOR:"#F0F0F0"}
    node:{TEXT1:"value1",TEXT2:"value2"}
};

pqr = {
    color: {PRIMARY_COLOR:"#FFFFFF",SECONDARY_COLOR:"#F0F0F0"}
    node:{WORD1:"value4",WORD2:"value5"}
};
```

Offnote: I am using following pattern which works fine.

```
key.matches("map.abc.*.*\\p{Lu}$") or key.matches("map.*.*\\p{Lu}$")
```

I am hence looking to find a way to get all keys ending with Uppercase alphabets after the last period in the Key from the HashMap(Or possibly any other options)

Comment: you'll have to iterate through the whole set of keys and check (with regex or simply splitting the string) which ones have the last part in uppercase.

Comment: You're using the wrong data structure for the job. A database would do this quite easily. Or else you need an auxiliary map.

Answer (score 1):

You can match the key with the following regex and see whether it returns true:

```
key.matches(".*\\.[A-Z]+");
```

Comment: thiw only works if the key ends in uppercase. his statement says any part of the key. though the examples show only ending in uppercase

Comment: One the other hand, the last line of the OP says that. I think, when he said last element, he meant the last chunk of his ". separated" string.

Comment: Just to clear up, if the key is "map.abc.color.SECONDARY" then I need the key which ends in uppercase after the final period. I was using the following pattern to retrieve it earlier and was working: key.matches("map.abc.*.*\\p{Lu}$") or may be key.matches("map.*.*\\p{Lu}$")

Answer (score 1):

OK, now that we have more detail, we can address your data structure.  It appears to me that you have a hierarchical map here.  Your `name` seems to define the hierarchy.  I'd use a map of maps to store it:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> structure = new HashMap<>();
```

to parse and populate the map (totally just psuedocode):

```
path = name.split(".")
// ignore path[0] since it's just 'map'
structure.get(path[1]).get(path[2]).put(path[3], value)
```

And to retrieve values

```
for (Map<String, Map<String, String>> element : structure){
  for(Map<String, String> group : element) {
    for(String attribute : group.keys){
      if(allUpper(attribute)) {  //DO YOUR THING HERE }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are trying to convert from a java properties-style list of values to javascript objects.

Here is one possibility: you could "unflatten" the properties-style `Map` into a recursive map of maps/values, and then leverage one of the JSON libraries to output the values.  Here is some code to unflatten things:

```
public class Foo {
  private static final String ROOT_NAME = "map";

  private static boolean noLowercase(CharSequence s) {
    return !s.chars().anyMatch(Character::isLowerCase);
  }

  private static Map<String, Object> getNextMap(Map<String, Object> map, String mapName) {
    Object nextObj = map.get(mapName);
    if (nextObj == null) {
      nextObj = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
      map.put(mapName, nextObj);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String, Object> nextMap = (Map<String, Object>)nextObj;
    return nextMap;
  }

  public static Map<String, Object> unflatten(Map<String, String> properties) {
    List<String> sortedKeys = new ArrayList<>(properties.keySet());
    Collections.sort(sortedKeys);
    Map<String, Object> rootObject = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (String key : sortedKeys) {
      String[] splitKey = key.split("\\.");
      String lastItem = splitKey[splitKey.length - 1];
      if (noLowercase(lastItem)) {
        Map<String, Object> currentMap = rootObject;
        for (int i = 1; i < splitKey.length - 1; ++i) {
          currentMap = getNextMap(currentMap, splitKey[i]);
        }
        currentMap.put(lastItem, properties.get(key));
      }
    }
    return rootObject;
  }
}
```

Serialising with, for example, Gson or Jackson should be pretty easy after this.  Here is an example using Gson:

```
  public static void printMap(Map<String, String> map) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : unflatten(map).entrySet()) {
      System.out.format("%s = ", entry.getKey());
      System.out.print(gson.toJson(entry.getValue()));
      System.out.println(";");
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
```

Alternatively it should not be too hard to write your own printing routines for the map of maps data structure.